# Check if Perl module exists on Cpan

Tags: cpan

I have a long list of Perl modules. I know some of them, but most not. I need to know which of them are available on Cpan. I know, i can copy and paste each item of the list into the cpan.org, but i want to learn a bit more about Perl and do this with a perl script.
I know that:

```
cpan -D ModName
```

will tell me which version is localy installed, and which is the latest on Cpan. Is there another way to get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this tutorial by Gabor Szabo](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-fetch-the-cpan-dependency-tree-of-a-perl-module). Not exactly related, but by using `MetaCPAN::API->module($module_name);` while looping on an array of your `@modules_names`, you could build a report of which module is available or not on CPAN. Not tested, but I wonder that if the module is not available, it will return `undef`.

Note that on the [documentation of MetaCpan::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/MetaCPAN::API), it's author considers the module as deprecated and recommend the use of [MetaCPAN::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/MetaCPAN::Client).

Comment: hi smonff, with your tips I found Module::CheckVersion which excatly does what I want, THX

Comment: Hi @roli, I tried to remember this one, bit didn't managed to. Maybe you should answer your own question with this for people who will later read this post.

Answer (score 1):

With smonff's tips I found [Module::CheckVersion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::CheckVersion) 
which exactly does what I want, THX.